# What purpose do the framing members in my garage attic serve?

Tags: framing, attic, timber-framing

Upon opening up the ceiling of the garage to install a fold-up attic ladder, I saw boards going from the gable beams to the attic floor beams.

This is the first time I have seen this. The house was constructed in 1958.  Do these boards take the place of cross beams?  If not, what purpose do they serve?

[image]

Comment: It's a terrible picture (hard to see the framing you ask about), but would appear to be a simple truss arrangment

Comment: Climbing a ladder and taking a picture from within the attic space, preferably with additional light, would provide a better basis to speculate from.

Comment: Are you seeing one of the roof trusses pictured here? http://www.biytoday.com/roofTrusses1.jpg

Comment: Does not look like trusses.   Ridge beam and rafters?   Stick Build it looks like to me.    Why are you trying to add attic steps?  Storage?   Please provide better pics, but before storing anything up there, you might want to consults a Structural Engineer to verify load capacity of the ceiling joists and proper reinforcement that may or may not be required.   Measurements of length of joists, dimensions of of the Joists(2x?)  span from one support wall or post to another wall , etc will help answer questions